# OpenLDAP Authentication UID vs CN issues

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, openldap, uid

I'm having trouble authenticating services using uid for authentication, which I thought was the standard method for authentication on the user. So basically, my users are added in ldap like this:

```
# jsmith, Users, example.com
dn: uid=jsmith,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
uidNumber: 10003
loginShell: /bin/bash
sn: Smith
mail: jsmith@example.com
homeDirectory: /home/jsmith
displayName: John Smith
givenName: John
uid: jsmith
gecos: John Smith
gidNumber: 10000
cn: John Smith
title: System Administrator
```

But when I try to authenticate using typical webapps or services like this:

```
jsmith
password
```

I get:

```
ldapsearch -x -h ldap.example.com -D "cn=jsmith,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com" -W -b "dc=example,dc=com"
Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

But if I use:

```
ldapsearch -x -h ldap.example.com -D "uid=jsmith,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com" -W -b "dc=example,dc=com"
```

It works.

HOWEVER...most webapps and authentication methods seem to use another method. So on a webapp I'm using, unless I specify the user as: `uid=smith,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com`
Nothing works.

In the webapp I just need users to put: jsmith in the user field.

Keep in mind my ldap is using the "new" `cn=config` method of storing settings. So if someone has an obvious ldif I'm missing please provide.

Let me know if you need further info. This is OpenLDAP on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Most applications that use LDAP for auth can be configured to tell them what to search for. In your first example, the app appears to search for the `cn`, not the `uid`,  and since the `cn` is `John Smith`, not `jsmith`, this cannot work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ldapsearch` tool in your example uses simple BIND to change the authorization state of the connection. The simple BIND operation requires the **distinguished name** and credentials. The distinguished name is `uid=jsmith,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com`, not `cn=jsmith,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com` in the entry given as example.

This directory server configuration causes the server to return the result code for `invalid credentials` when actually the distinguished name `cn=jsmith,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com` doe not exist. This is the recommended configuration: it provides less information to an attacker.